# Ubuntu 18.04 server with 2 NICs

Tags: iptables, routing

I am running a Ubuntu 18.04 server with 2 NICs both with static IPs as shown in the yaml below.

NIC 1 (enp5so) is connected to a router on 192.168.46.1. Both NIC's are functioning fine with NIC 1 able to access the internet thru the router and the server being accessable via NIC 2 (enp2so / 192.168.48.1) using ssh without any issues but cannot access the internet from NIC 2.

How do I route the traffic from NIC 2 thru NIC 1 to access the internet? An iptables listing is also shown below.

```
yaml:
 /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml                                                                        

network:

    version: 2
    ethernets:
        enp5s0:
            dhcp4: no
            dhcp6: no
            addresses: [192.168.46.2/24]
            gateway4:  192.168.46.1
            nameservers:
                addresses: [192.168.46.1, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
        enp2s0:
            addresses: [192.168.48.1/24]
            gateway4:  192.168.46.1
            nameservers:
                addresses: [192.168.46.1, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

iptables:

```
-P INPUT DROP    
-P FORWARD DROP    
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT    
-N ICMP    
-N TCP    
-N UDP    
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT    
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT    
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP    
-A INPUT -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j UDP    
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j TCP    
-A INPUT -p icmp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ICMP    
-A INPUT -p udp -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable    
-A INPUT -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset    
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-proto-unreachable    
-A TCP -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7822 -j ACCEPT    
-A TCP -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5901 -j ACCEPT    
-A TCP -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT    
-A TCP -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT    
-A TCP -p tcp -m tcp --dport 137 -j ACCEPT    
-A TCP -p tcp -m tcp --dport 138 -j ACCEPT    
-A TCP -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -j ACCEPT    
-A TCP -p tcp -m tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT    
-A TCP -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT
```